# Concatenate key and value in dictionary<string,<IEnumerable string>> to make one list

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have

```
Dictionary<string,IEnumerable<string>> pathAndItems = new Dictionary<string,IEnumerable<String>>();
```

such as

```
this/is/path/: {hey, ho, lets, go}
another/path/: {hey, hello}
```

what I want to do is make one IEnumerable with all concatenaded values.

```
this/is/path/hey, this/is/path/ho, this/is/path/lets, this/is/path/go, another/path/hey, another/path/hello
```

I can get all in one, but how can I prepend the key to each?

```
var SL_requirements = SL_requirementsDict.SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value);
```

edit: I would like to do it as a LINQ expression rather than loops

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are various ways of skinning this. `SelectMany` lets you specify what to do with each `(source, projected-element)` pair too, either in a query expression or not:

```
var query = from pair in dictionary
            from value in pair.Value
            select pair.Key + "/" + value;
```

Or in dot notation:

```
var query = dictionary.SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value,
                                  (kvp, value) => kvp.Key + "/" + value);
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it wouldn't be that hard. Just my brain going on pre-lunch capacity :)